# Changing button text of different button on button click

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 3 buttons in my storyboard and ViewController that are working as expected:

```
- (IBAction)button0:(id)sender {
    [sender setTitle:@"btn0 pressed" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
- (IBAction)button1:(id)sender {
    [sender setTitle:@"btn1 pressed" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
- (IBAction)button2:(id)sender {
    [sender setTitle:@"btn2 pressed" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

I have a fourth button that, when pressed, I would like to change the displayed text of button0-2 to an empty string.

```
- (IBAction)resetAllButtons:(id)sender {
    //In Android this code would be something like:
    //Button btn0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button0);
    //btn0.setText(" ");
}
```

How do I do this? I've found many ways to change the button text, but only of the current button being pressed.  Can I target all the buttons by id somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out (although still not clear on why it works?)

I connected button0 as an IBOutlet in my ViewController.h file.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button0;
```

From there I was able to reference it in my ViewController.m file using

```
[self.button0 setTitle:@" " forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

But why am I able to do that?  I thought that if I declared

```
- (IBAction)button0:(id)sender;
```

in my ViewControler.h file that I couldn't also have an outlet connected to the same object?  Thanks for reading either way.

Comment: Glad you figured it out :) 
When you declare `(IBAction)button0:(id)sender` you are not saying you have a **button** called _button0_, you are just saying something kind of  _"Hey Xcode, here's some function I want to trigger when the user does something"_ (you may have noticed in the IB that you can assign that action to different events as touchUpInside, touchUpOutside, etc)

With just that statement, Xcode has no idea there's a button called *button0*. You need to declare and then hook it up in the Interface Builder. To avoid confusion try naming IBActions as button0Tapped, for example

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification :)